# Web app taking too long to determine whether user is authenticated or not

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js, google-authentication

## Background info

I have just started using/ learning how to use Next.js and I'm facing an issue where my user authentication logic is making my components take a long time to render on the page. I believe I'm missing something really fundamental and I'm not sure if it's Next.js related or something to do with how I'm handling user states across my application.

I'm using Firebase's Google Authentication to handle my user login.

The code I will be referring to in my question exists in the following repository:
https://github.com/myamazingthrowaway/nextjswebsite

A live demo of the app can be found here:
https://nextjswebsite-kappa-sand.now.sh/

(it uses cross-site cookies to handle firebase google login - I don't know how to change this default behaviour, so if it doesn't work first time, make sure your browser allows cross-site cookies)

I based my authentication logic on the following repository:
https://github.com/taming-the-state-in-react/nextjs-redux-firebase-authentication

My web app was made with `create-next-app`.

## The Problem

When a user visits my website, the sidebar component and the rest of the components which rely on the logged in state of the user don't appear immediately on page load. They appear some time after the initial page is rendered. It's a significant delay and there is no 'loading indicator' on my chrome tab to say that the dom is still being built 
Is this the expected behaviour?

The issue can also be seen on the following site (signing in with google demonstrates what I mean).

Steps to reproduce: 

1. Go to: https://kage.saltycrane.com/

2. Press 'Sign In'

3. Press 'Sign In with Google'

 You will get redirected to the google sign in page, select an account etc. (to sign in)

 Then you will be redirected back to the site in step 1, where the menu bar at the top still remains 'Sign in'.. for a moment or two, before it changes to your email address.

Why does this happen?

(the code behind the webpage above is here: https://github.com/saltycrane/kage)

## My Code

In my `_app.js` file, I have a 'Shell' component which handles my sidebar & navbar for the entire web app. It accepts child components to be rendered within the confines of the sidebar etc. Perhaps this isn't the best way to handle how the application flows (would be more than happy for suggestions on how to improve this).

The `_app.js` file looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";

import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";

import initStore from "../src/store";
import theme from "../src/theme";

import Shell from "../src/components/Shell";

class EnhancedApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    return {
      pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");

    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <title>Next.js</title>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Shell>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Shell>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRedux(initStore)(EnhancedApp);
```

My `Shell` component looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Router from "next/router";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
  Drawer,
  List,
  Divider,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Hidden,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { ProfileIcon } from "../index";

import MonetizationOnOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MonetizationOnOutlined";
import AccountBalanceWalletRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountBalanceWalletRounded";
import AccountBoxRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountBoxRounded";
import VpnKeyRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VpnKeyRounded";
import ExitToAppRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExitToAppRounded";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import * as routes from "../../constants/routes";
import { auth } from "../../firebase/firebase";

const drawerWidth = 180;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0
    }
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  appBar: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg,  #FF8E53 30%, #ff4d73 90%)",
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`
    }
  },
  logoContainer: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #ff4d73 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "15rem"
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      display: "none"
    }
  },
  rightAlign: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: -12,
    cursor: "pointer"
  },
  hoverCursor: {
    cursor: "pointer"
  }
}));

const Shell = ({ children, authUser }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleGoToEarnPage = () => {
    Router.push(routes.EARN);
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const handleGoToSignInPage = () => {
    Router.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const handleGoToWithdrawPage = () => {
    Router.push(routes.WITHDRAW);
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const handleGoToProfilePage = () => {
    Router.push(routes.PROFILE);
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const handleGoToHomePage = () => {
    Router.push(routes.LANDING);
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth.signOut();
    if (mobileOpen) handleDrawerToggle();
  };

  const drawer = (
    <>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar className={classes.logoContainer}>
          <img
            src="/images/logo/logo.png"
            alt="my logo"
            height="120rem"
            onClick={handleGoToHomePage}
            className={classes.hoverCursor}
          />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <List>
        <ListItem button key="Earn" href="/earn" onClick={handleGoToEarnPage}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <MonetizationOnOutlinedIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Earn" />
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem
          button
          key="Withdraw"
          href="/withdraw"
          onClick={handleGoToWithdrawPage}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <AccountBalanceWalletRoundedIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Withdraw" />
        </ListItem>

        <Divider variant="middle" />
        {!authUser && (
          <List>
            <ListItem
              button
              key="Sign In"
              href="/signin"
              onClick={handleGoToSignInPage}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <VpnKeyRoundedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Sign In" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        )}

        {authUser && (
          <List>
            <ListItem
              button
              key="Profile"
              href="/profile"
              onClick={handleGoToProfilePage}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <AccountBoxRoundedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Profile" />
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem button key="Sign Out" onClick={handleSignOut}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <ExitToAppRoundedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Sign Out" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        )}
      </List>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <div className={classes.rightAlign}>
            {authUser && <ProfileIcon className={classes.hoverCursor} />}
            {!authUser && (
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleGoToSignInPage}>
                Sign In
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="sidebar">
        <Hidden mdUp>
          <Drawer
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={classes.direction === "rtl" ? "right" : "left"}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smDown>
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>

      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {children}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authUser: state.sessionState.authUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Shell);
```

As you can see, the `Shell` component uses a HOC to wrap it with an `authUser` prop from the session state. I don't know if this is what causes issues when loading the page?

The `ProfileIcon` component doesn't load immediately when user signs in either. Similarly to the `kage` website I mentioned earlier. I don't understand why this happens. I feel like my code is all over the place.

My `signin.js` page looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { AppWithAuthentication } from "../src/components/App";
import { auth, provider } from "../src/firebase/firebase";
import { db } from "../src/firebase";
import * as routes from "../src/constants/routes";

const SignInPage = () => (
  <AppWithAuthentication>
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <SignInForm />
  </AppWithAuthentication>
);

const updateByPropertyName = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
  [propertyName]: value
});

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
  error: null
};

class SignInForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };

    if (auth.currentUser) {
      console.log(`already signed in`);
      Router.push(routes.HOME);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);

        // add them to the db and then redirect
        db.doCreateUser(
          user.uid,
          user.email,
          user.displayName,
          user.photoURL,
          false
        )
          .then(() => {
            this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
            Router.push(routes.HOME);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState(updateByPropertyName("error", error));
          });
      } else {
        console.log(`No active user found. User must log in`);
      }
    });
  }

  onClick = () => {
    auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.onClick}>
        Sign In with Google
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default SignInPage;

export { SignInForm };
```

Where `AppWithAuthentication` looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { compose } from "recompose";

import withAuthentication from "../Session/withAuthentication";
import withAuthorisation from "../Session/withAuthorisation";

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="app">
    {children}
  </div>
);

const AppWithAuthentication = compose(
  withAuthentication,
  withAuthorisation(false)
)(App);

const AppWithAuthorisation = compose(
  withAuthentication,
  withAuthorisation(true)
)(App);

export { AppWithAuthentication, AppWithAuthorisation };
```

So whenever a user goes onto my webpage and tries to access any 'authenticated only' route, they will see the content of the route first for a few seconds, **then** get redirected to the sign in page. I don't want this to happen and I cannot see why this happens either.

How can I fix these issues? I'm completely stuck for ideas. Need a fresh pair of eyes to help me understand where the issue is.

Comment: There are several way on how you can prevent to show authenticated only contents, you can do server side checks or use a HOC component that show something else while checking if user is logged for example.

Comment: @Nico Does this mean that my application's current behaviour is expected? Will the said above fix my issues? If so, would you be able to link an example on how to achieve the said above please?

Comment: It's expected for server authentication to take a second. You can show a loading screen while waiting for it to complete.

Comment: During an initial page load, the user's authentication state is "pending". You can't confirm whether a user is logged in or not until their state is resolved and that's when any `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` handlers get notified. On such a page load, you should be rendering a full page loading throbber while you wait and possibly preload the component ready for rendering once you know the user state is determined.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the request of the authentication process waiting on a response. 
Check your network connections in chrome with developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) -> Network -> Then reload your app and see the requests firing. You will notice your state will wait on https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=xxx to return a response with the google account name etc. after you click sign in and select an account.

Make the loaders visibility dependant on the information the request returns (create a variable in your state (exp.: user) and once you have the user info from google set it to the user object. Then you can say !user -> show loader. You can also trigger the loader with an additional state variable that gets set true when you click on sign in.

Considering you are using firebase, look into https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial for some more info. I would include code here as well, but I think you can use this information to build what I said according to how you want to structure your app. Shouldn't be too big of a deal. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    return {
      pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {}
    };
  }
```

Let nextjs do the optimization it self.
when you handle the initial props yourself, the optimization is lost.